# json_decode for PHP joomla

Tags: php, json

Need help. I am having trouble solving this json thingy. here's what is on my database

> *{"img":["images/logo2.png","images/logo.png"]}*

I need to decode this images and show it like this

> images/logo2.png
>   images/logo.png

Comment: And? What's stopping you?

Comment: if you add some attempt example it would be easier to help you out in what you are doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search will give you this link: [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
$someJson = '{"img":["images/logo2.png","images/logo.png"]}';
$encodeJson = json_decode($someJson, true);

echo $encodeJson['img'][0]; //images/logo2.png
echo $encodeJson['img'][1]; //images/logo.png
```

**Hint:** Having a look at the PHP-Manual is not prohibited. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe select your entry from database and put in a variable called $dataBaseEntry then copy paste this code?

```
$decoded = json_decode($dataBaseEntry, true); //true for associated array 
$logos = $decoded['img'];
print_r($logos)
```